# sklearn dictionary learning: parameter tuning

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So I'm doing dictionary learning on a set of my own images, adapting heavily from the [denoising example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_image_denoising.html#example-decomposition-plot-image-denoising-py). My rough workflow is:

- unravel all my images into a vector of length 2700 (images are originally (3, 30, 30)).
- get an input matrix of shape (`n_images`, 2700).
- Use MiniBatchDL:

```
dico = MiniBatchDictionaryLearning(n_components=5000, alpha=2, transform_algorithm='omp', n_iter=1000)
V = dico.fit(data).components_`
```

But my dictionary's still learning some patches of noise, which is affecting the encoding representation later.

- does anyone have any pointers as to how to tune `n_components` and `alpha`? The original papers, mostly by Michael Elad, don't have many such details of execution. I've considered [grid search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html), but I'd like to see if there are any handy analytical pointers or heuristics first, due to the punitive run time of each run. The little code snippet above took 13h.
- Is `n_iter` just a case of "the more the merrier"? From the docs, this method doesn't have a tolerance criterion to terminate, so the number of iterations has to be input manually.